# How to set Qt pushbutton like this

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, stylesheet, qpushbutton

I try to write a simple Player with Qt.

I try to set `Play` button look like this

[image: pushbutton style]

Use stylesheet or use a QPixmap like a button.

My code is

```
playCtrl = new QPushButton(this);
playCtrl->setIcon(QIcon(QPixmap(":/icons/icons/play.png")));
playCtrl->setIconSize(QSize(150, 150));
playCtrl->setStyleSheet("QPushButton{background-image:url(:/icons/icons/play.png)}");
```

but when I run my code, I just got this:

[image]

---

I'm very happy to say, I had solve this problem.

Just use this:

```
playCtl = new QPushButton(this);
playCtl->setIcon(QIcon(QPixmap(":/icons/icons/player_play.png")));
playCtl->setIconSize(QSize(32, 32));
playCtl->setStyleSheet("QPushButton{border: none;outline: none;}");
```

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? For good answers, it is best to post some code and  describe how it behaves differently from what you expect, see also [The FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). In your case, did you try to use `QPushButton::setIcon()`?

Comment: use photoshop to make the image; then set it as the image of the button.

Comment: But my button still have a frame..

Comment: can you try playCtrl->setFlat(true)? I found it on google but not sure about it since i currently don't have qt installed.

Comment: QPushButton::setFlat(bool);

Comment: Ok you solved it. That's really nice!

Comment: You could also implement your own button subclassing from QAbstractButton and reimplement paintEvent(). Then you don't have to try that hard to turn off unwanted UI elements such as borders and bevel. It would avoid surprises when on other platforms/using different styles.

Comment: @midCat when you solve the problem you should post it as an answer and accept it so that others can see that your problem is solved stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer